# Using a service from a non-Spring Groovy class

Tags: java, spring, grails, dependency-injection

I am implementing a custom InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEventListener to react on events from the spring-security-core plugin - the source file is in /src/groovy

In this class, how can I use a service defined in grails-app/services ? Dependency-injection (obviously?) does not work.

Comment: why not pass what you need to the groovy src instead of using DI in the groovy src?

Comment: hmm... if nothing else works, i will have to try that, i assume - a singleton or a class with static service methods, but then again whats the point with DI anyway?

Comment: @thomers The point of DI is that you write classes that depend on abstractions rather than particular implementations of those abstractions. DI also takes care of wiring together a class and it's dependencies, so you don't have to write that code yourself. This means you can write loosely-coupled classes, which makes them more flexible. This is particularly beneficial when you want to test a class as you can easily mock out it's dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two options

1. pass the dependencies into the class
2. retrieve the spring bean within the class using a helper class such as

---

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsApplicationAttributes
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext

public class SpringUtils {

    static getSpringBean(String name) {
        getApplicationContext().getBean(name);
    }

    static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return ServletContextHolder.getServletContext().getAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT);
    }    
}
```

The first option is better IMO

Comment: I agree - pass the dependencies into the class.